# selecting bigest value among data

Tags: python, excel, bash, matlab

I have following data

[image]

I'd like to select the bigest value on 2nd column related to value on 1st column.
For value 1 on 1st column, the selected value shall be 5.

The 1st column is time (for example: 06:54:11)

I can use matlab, python, excel, bash.

Comment: Please, never show text with images. They are not searchable, not copy-paste-able and much heavier than needed. Moreover they affect accessibility negatively. Please copy-paste the text in your question and [format it properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), instead. In this case, without knowing the text-only version of your data we cannot suggest anything. Moreover you state that the first column is time (for example `06:54:11`) but what you show has nothing to do with this (`1`, `2`..) Please clarify.

Comment: Step 1: Partition your sample data into "packages" where the value of the first column is equal. Step 2: Find the highest number in each "package".

Comment: When asking a question, restrict yourself to one language (for instance python). Tagging this in more than one does not make much sense. Also, post the code you have already written for this, and describe at which point you got stuck.

Comment: @user1934428, I need some solution. I really don't care which language it will be  as there are some farther analysis that I'm doing.

Comment: @user1977050 SO is not a free coding service. Please show what you tried up to now and explain why it did not work as expected. And please also address my first comment: as it is now your question is not accurate enough to receive an answer.

Comment: @user1977050 : If you need someone providing a solution for you, this is not the right place to ask. May I suggest that you post your problem [here](https://www.freelance.com/) or [here](https://www.guru.com/m/hire/freelancers/computer-programmers/)?

Comment: the image shows column #1 having values of `1` and `2`, but in the description you state the column #1 is a time (eg, `06:54:11`) ... which is it ... integer or time? please update the question to show the actual data you're working with

Answer (score 2):

Using python, you can download your file (assuming it's an Excel file) to a pandas DataFrame, `groupby` on the first column and find the `max` value in the second column:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('your_data.xlsx')
output = df.groupby('column1')['column2'].max()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Matlab you can get the Maximum with the build-in "max" function.

Try using [M,I] = max(data)
and replace data with your matrix name.

M will return you the maxima. In your case M(2) will be the maximum of the second row. With the Index (I) you can grab the corresponding time out of the first row.
time = data(I(2),1)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).